# check if directory entries are files or directories using ruby

Tags: ruby

Okay.  I'm a big noob at Ruby.  What did I miss?

I just want to iterate through a particular folder on OS X and if a sub-entry is a directory I want to do something.

My code:

```
folder = gets.chomp()
Dir.foreach(folder) do |entry|
  puts entry unless File.directory?(entry)
  # unfortunately directory?
  # doesn't work as expected here because everything evaluates to false, but why?  How is this supposed to be done?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entry` contains only basename part (`dirname/basename`). You need to join it with `folder` to get correct path.

```
folder = gets.chomp()
Dir.foreach(folder) do |entry|
  path = File.join(folder, entry) # <------
  puts entry unless File.directory?(path)
end
```

In addition to that, you maybe want to skip entry if the `entry` is `.` or `..`.

```
  next if entry == '.' || entry == '..'
```